# How do I compare a variable that asks for user input to the user's input?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;
public class Name2
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        String name;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter your name: ");
        name = scan.nextLine();
        // asks for user input

        if(name.equals(Person)) 
        // this is my problem. The .equals() method doesn't work

        System.out.println("Hey buddy!");
        else
        System.out.println("This is just an example");
    }
}
```

This is what I have tried with no luck. The `.equals()` method doesn't work.

Comment: What is the Person you want to comapre to? It seems like a class, in that case you should instantiate the class first, then you can reach it's variables/methods.

Comment: Please post a valid SSCCE (http://sscce.org/).. Person is not defined anywhere in your code, so it won't even compile..

Comment: Person is just an example to what the user will input so it is not a variable.

Answer (score 4):

The issue isn't that `.equals()` does not work. The issue is that `Person` is not defined.

If you meant that as a literal string, you need to put double quotes around it: `"Person"`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you forgot "" on the `if(name.equals(Person))`

That might be `if(name.equals("Person"))`

You can try  `if( name.equalsIgnoreCase("Person"))` if you need accept any lowercase and uppercase.

Comment: @JorgeRosas if you want get into true part give exactly Person as your input.

Answer (score 1):

you need to create a String variable to compare Person to.
it should look like:
String Person = "Dave";

You may also want to put an else statement to say something else if the names don't match.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments that you have received correctly, you first need to define what 'Person' really is.

**If Person is a string representation** of an input you would need to edit your code in this manner:

```
    String name;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter your name: ");
    name = scan.nextLine();
    // asks for user input

    // Wrap Person in double quotes
    if (name.equals("Person"))
        System.out.println("Hey buddy!");
    else
        System.out.println("This is just an example");
```

The Output would be:

```
Please enter your name: 
Person
Hey buddy!
```

**If Person is a user defined object** then you would first need to define a Person object overriding the equals method.

*Person Object*

```
public class Person
{
    private String name;

    public Person(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Person other = (Person) obj;
        if (name == null) {
            if (other.name != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
            return false;
        return true;
}
```

*Then use the Person object to compare what you are inputting in your stream through your main method.*

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Construct and initialise Person
    Person person = new Person("Person");

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter your name: ");
    Person name = new Person(scan.nextLine());
    // asks for user input

    // Use the person object for name instead of String
    if (name.equals(person))
        System.out.println("Hey buddy!");
    else
        System.out.println("This is just an example");

}
```

*You should get your desired output, i.e.*

```
Please enter your name: 
Person
Hey buddy!
```

Answer (score 0):

**equals()** will work in your case if you compare it with a String.

Use `if(name.equals("Person"))` instead of `if(name.equals(Person))`

PS : I doubt if the second expression that you used will even get compiled.